# What does : means in a function parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was checking the facebook sdk and came accross this function:

```
FB.ShareLink(
    new Uri("https://developers.facebook.com/"),
    callback: ShareCallback
);
```

My question is, does the callback: means?, Is it stating that parameter should be linked with that callback? if so what is the benefit of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`callback:` is called "named parameter". It means that in the sharelink, there is a named parameter called as "callback" and you fill the callback parameter with `ShareCallback`.

Named parameters are very useful if there are a lot of overload parameters, and we want to make sure that the parameter name that we use is the correct one.

[This](https://www.dotnetperls.com/named-parameters) might help you understand more.

Answer (score 4):

This is called a named parameter. It can be used to more clearly document what your code is doing, or to call a method where some of the parameters have default values without specifying all the parameters explicitly.